# How to develop a RESTful API for an existing web app using ZEND's framework?

Tags: api, zend-framework, rest

Does anyone has experience with ZEND's framework for writing a RESTful API for an existing web app?
Do you any good tutorial that explain that?
My web app is written with PHP and I want to build a 3rd party API.

Thanks!

Comment: Five questions and no single accepted answer? Yeah, better work on that ratio.

Comment: I am also trying to do this. It looks like they have modified the Zend Framework and removed the require()'s so they can use their own AutoLoader... I am afraid it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup a zend framework project like you normally would do and `disable the view` to retrieve just the data you need.

```
$this->_helper->layout ()->disableLayout ();
```

[This might be a good start ;)](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Zend_Rest_Route?  I use it to route REST request for my API (i.e. get, post, put, and delete).